# How to get consonant repeated, but not vowel in Python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I have two functions, the first one is related to the second, and it codes for whether or not a letter is a vowel (True) or a consonant (False).

```
def vowel(c):
    """(str) -> bool
    Return whether the string c is a vowel.
    >>> vowel('e')
    True
    >>> vowel('t')
    False
    """
    for char in c:
        if char.lower() in 'aeiou':
            return True
        else:
            return False


def repeated(s, k):
    """(str) -> str
    Return a string where consonants in the string s is repeated k times.
    >>> repeated('', 24)
    ''
    >>> repeated('eoa', 2)
    'eoa'
    >>> repeated('m', 5)
    'mmmmm'
    >>> repeated('choice', 4)
    'cccchhhhoicccce'
    """
    result = ''

    for c in s:
        if c is not vowel(c):
            result = result + (c * k)
    return result
```

This is what I have for the function, but the examples fail and doesn't skip the vowels.

```
    repeat('eoa', 2)
Expected:
    'eoa'
Got:
    'eeooaa'
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Keep going ! Programming can be fun. Do your exercise.

Comment: When you get it right it's fun - thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. Do not forget to tell the community whether you are satisfied by a given answer by ticking it as the correct one. See *[What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things. In the `vowel` function, there's no need for a loop. You're sending a single character so you simply need to check it:

```
def vowel(c):
    if c.lower() in 'aeiou':
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Or:

```
def vowel(c):
    return True if c.lower() in 'aeiou' else False
```

Then, in `repeated`, don't use `c is not vowel(c)`. That compares if the identity of `c`, the character, is or isn't equal to `True/False`. Just use the value returned from `vowel` directly and conditionally add to `result`:

```
def repeated(s, k):
    result = ''
    for c in s:
        if not vowel(c):
            result += (c * k)
        else:
            result += c
    return result
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it makes much more sense now!